# UITextField set placeholder color as dark in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, placeholder

I have tried to set `UITextField` **"Placeholder"** color as dark.

```
NSAttributedString * search = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Search" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}];

textField.attributedPlaceholder = search;
```

- But still `UITextField` showing light gray color in **"Placeholder"**.
- Is it possible to set dark **"placeholder"** color for `UITextField`?

Also I Have tried the another method as well

```
[textField setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

But both methods are working in **iOS 7**, But not working on **iOS 6**.

- Is it possible to set dark **"placeholder"** color for `UITextField` in **iOS 6** target?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted should work - it does for me. Make sure there is no call to set the regular `placeholder` property after this. Also make sure `textField` isn't `nil` when you call the code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As suggested by Apple, subclassing UITextField and overriding `- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect` is the way to go:

```
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect { 
    UIColor *colour = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; 
    if ([self.placeholder respondsToSelector:@selector(drawInRect:withAttributes:)]) 
    { // iOS7 and later 
        NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour, NSFontAttributeName: self.font}; 
        CGRect boundingRect = [self.placeholder boundingRectWithSize:rect.size options:0 attributes:attributes context:nil]; 
        [self.placeholder drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, (rect.size.height/2)-boundingRect.size.height/2) withAttributes:attributes]; } 
    else { // iOS 6 
        [colour setFill]; 
        [self.placeholder drawInRect:rect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail alignment:self.textAlignment]; 
    } 
 }
```

Credit: http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/how-change-colour-uitextfields-placeholder-text-ios7-and-still-support-ios6

Comment: Works in iOS8 as well.

Answer (score 9):

Overriding the `drawPlaceholderInRect:` method to draw our own placeholder text.

```
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIColor *colour = [UIColor darkColor];
    
    if ([self.placeholder respondsToSelector:@selector(drawInRect:withAttributes:)]) {
        // iOS7 and later
        NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour, NSFontAttributeName: self.font};
        CGRect boundingRect = [self.placeholder boundingRectWithSize:rect.size options:0 attributes:attributes context:nil];
        [self.placeholder drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, (rect.size.height/2)-boundingRect.size.height/2) withAttributes:attributes];
    }
    else {
        // iOS 6
        [colour setFill];
        [self.placeholder drawInRect:rect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail alignment:self.textAlignment];
    }
}
```

***OR***

This case, likely crash if the internal variable changes in the future

*Programmatically:*

```
  [self.MyTextField setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

In `UIStoryBoard`:

[image]

**OR**

**EDIT:**
Playing with UITextFiled delegates. its like a tricky:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  self.mytxtField.text = @"PlaceholderText";
  self.mytxtField.delegate = self;
   self.mytxtField.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
           if ([self.mytxtField.text isEqualToString: @"PlaceholderText"]) {
             self.mytxtField.text = @"";
             self.mytxtField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
        }
    }


-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
      if ([self.mytxtField.text length]<1) {
            self.mytxtField.text =@"PlaceholderText";
            self.mytxtField.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor]; 

        }
```

Comment: Will this feature has been changed in feature? I mean, Is it efficient way to customize UITextField?

Comment: what do you mean in the way of efficient.?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use this approach. It accesses the private subview structure of the text field. It could fail in any future iOS update.

Comment: So, What will be the efficient way to update the UITextField Placeholder color as dark? @rmaddy

Comment: @rmaddy : Can you plz, expand it  **It accesses the private subview structure of the text field**.. even I'm not sure about it so..

Comment: I mean exactly what I say. Calling `setValue:` with the key path of `_placeholderLabel` is a way to access the private ivar `_placeholderLabel`. You are not supposed to access private ivars. Apple could rename that ivar in iOS 8, for example. Then this code will stop working.

Comment: Even worse than not working, the second solution will likely crash if the internal variable changes in the future, forcing you to release an update and hope your users update. The first solution is ok as it checks if the variable exists and in future releases would "fail silently".

Comment: @Rivera : Yes, I agree to you. How about the edited one.

Answer (score 9):

For iOS8, you can take advantage of `@IBDesignable` & `@IBInspectable`.

Here is a UITextField subclass in Swift which lets you set the placeholder color in Interface Builder and see the result instantly:

```
@IBDesignable class EDTextField: UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var placeholderColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
        didSet {
            if let placeholder = self.placeholder {
                let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeholderColor]
                attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: attributes)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How cool is that ... never heard of `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` before, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

#### Its very simple....

Try this to change placeholder text color..

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:placeholderText attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];
```

Comment: Why use a different approach for iOS 6? iOS 6 supports the `attributePlaceholder` property.

Comment: As I commented on the other answer, Method 2 will start crashing your app as soon as the implementation changes in a future iOS release.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Latest way to Change FONT and COLOR of placeholder text

```
    self.emailField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Email" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],NSFontAttributeName :[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:14.0]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 [textField setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Comment: This will cause an exception in iOS 13: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Access to UITextField's _placeholderLabel ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug'`

Answer (score 0):

To make it future-proof and completely customizable (color, font, size, etc.), I would just add a `UILabel` on top and hide/show it manually according to the `UITextField` contents.

Just make sure to set the label's `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`.

Comment: Hi, I would like to use iOS feature as textField.attributedPlaceholder. But this method is working in iOS 7, But not working on iOS 6. Thoughts?

Comment: I understand, but changing the placeholder's text color for instance is not an "iOS feature", a reason why I suggest using a customized `UILabel` instead. This is guaranteed to work on iOS 6/7/8+.

Answer (score 0):

It will change `textField`'s palceholder textColor

```
[yourTextField setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:150.0f/255.0f green:150.0f/255.0f blue:155.0f/255.0f alpha:1] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```